# Java: get notified when object field changes

Tags: java, field, private, notify

I am using GSON to serialize/deserialize objects. GSON directly sets the fields of objects when deserializing. My issue is that I need to be notified when this happens. The field value needs to be propagated to some other object immediately.

Is this possible, for example via reflection?

According to [How to create change listener for variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable) I need to create a setter or any other wrapper. But GSON doesn't use this. So, what are my options?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757902/java-field-change-listener, but no answer there.